# Estimate about $\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\log \frac xn$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I'm finding the estimate of $$\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\log \frac xn$$
There is a formula saying that $$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)G\bigg(\frac xn\bigg)=\sum_{n\leq x}g(n)F\bigg(\frac xn\bigg)$$
where $F(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)$ and $G(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}g(n)$. So I want to express $\log x$ in the form $$\log x=\sum_{n\leq x}g(n)$$
for some function $g$. but what I really know is $$\log n=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\log\dfrac nd$$
not the same as what I want. Any suggestion? I also appreciate different way to do this.

Comment: What is $\mu(n)$?

Comment: @StefanLafon It is the Möbius Function.

Comment: $\int_1^\infty (\sum_{n \le x} \mu(n)(\log x -\log n)) x^{-s-1}dx = \frac{1}{s^2\zeta(s)}$

so assuming the zeros are simple and after a lot of estimates to show it converges, there is the explicit formula $\sum_{n \le x} \mu(n)(\log x -\log n) = \sum Res(\frac{1}{s^2\zeta(s)} x^s) = \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho^2 \zeta'(\rho)}-\frac{\zeta'(0)}{\zeta(0)^2}+\frac{\log x}{\zeta(0)} +\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{-2k}}{(-2k)^2 \zeta'(-2k)}$. The RH is true iff it is $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$.

Comment: What is the context in which the need to estimate the sum arose? If hardly anything is known about $\mu$, one cannot improve much on the trivial $$\biggl\lvert \sum_{n \leqslant x} \mu(n)\log \frac{x}{n}\biggr\rvert \leqslant \sum_{n \leqslant x} \lvert\mu(n)\rvert \log \frac{x}{n} \leqslant \sum_{n \leqslant x} \log \frac{x}{n} \sim x\,.$$ One can note that $$\sum_{n \leqslant x} \mu(n)\log \frac{x}{n} = \int_1^x \frac{M(u)}{u}\,du\,,$$ so bounds for the Mertens function yield bounds for the sum. But it's more likely that the sum shall be used to obtain bounds for the Mertens function.

Comment: Then one can note that $$\sum_{n \leqslant x} \mu(n)\log \frac{x}{n} = \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \frac{x^s}{s^2\zeta(s)}\,ds\,,$$ and a different evaluation of the integral yields estimates for the sum. A typical way for a different evaluation of the integral is shifting the contour. One needs estimates for $1/\zeta(s)$ and information about the location of the zeros of $\zeta$ to obtain an $O(x\exp(-c\sqrt[\alpha]{\log x})$ bound this way (the value of $\alpha$ depends on the zero-free region you know).